# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "and 403 forbidden(But works fine in codepen and localhost)

Tags: html, css

[**This is the codepen demo it works fine**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGYgBo) .The same after uploading to server stops working properly and almost all the external references are showing 404.In the initial week there was no such problem after that its like This 
**!-->** [**http://sachin.ipoverload.com/almostComplete.html**](http://sachin.ipoverload.com/almostComplete.html)

**Using absolute urls**

```
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**why is this happening 403 Forbidden error in server but not in codepen why**??

---

### Please ignore the 404 error due to relative urls .Instead of them i am trying to use online repositories My question is Directed to above mentioned urls

Comment: Just to check, have you tried to use _type="text/css"_ inside the link tag?

Comment: t's not required with the HTML5 spec, but for older versions of HTML is it required.

Comment: when i look in your code and click on font awsome css get error, it won't wind it. is your url ok?

Comment: Are you completely sure your js and css files are in /css and /js folders?

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you have different urls on your website.

This is what I find on  section:
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/A.bootstrap,,_3.2.0,,_css,,_bootstrap.min.css+font-awesome,,_4.1.0,,_css,,_font-awesome.min.css,Mcc.t3GI5K-i_L.css.pagespeed.cf.NJHTdcjXGM.css

Comment: I have noticed that my question is that why is this happenning check out my link given in codepen and yes its show 403 in case of server and not in case of codepen .So in short you are asking me the same question

Comment: No, codepen link looks like this: http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Please use webdev tools and check what is your real sourcecode. You have broken links, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: i am using chrome and firefox and have tried both while http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css is the address when it is loaded in codepen and local host but when uploaded onto server url turns to what you have been saying http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/A.bootstrap,,_3.2.0,,_css,,_bootstrap.min.css+font-awesome,,_4.1.0,,_css,,_font-awesome.min.css,Mcc.t3GI5K-i_L.css.pagespeed.cf.NJHTdcjXGM.css

Comment: Just checks what is changing those urls. There is something on your server/app that changes it. It's not javascript since using view-source::(url) result in the same result.